# I've read a 2 year old rhubarb root can weigh 100 lbs, is this true?

Tags: rhubarb

I've read that 2 year old rhubarb roots can weigh 100 lbs, and was wondering what species this would be.

> At only 2 years old, the roots weigh 100 pounds apiece, and French and his son pick them up by hand.
> https://www.lancasterfarming.com/farming/produce/rhubarb-growing-comes-out-of-the-dark/article_28efb37f-c0a7-5c1d-b5a8-0da939c2957b.html

Comment: I don’t know any plant that grows that fast. Certainly not rhubarb.